# How to have custom control in DataGridView display object's value?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

I have a sample project located [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=ba8db0c447edb711%211334).

The project has a main form `Form1` where the user can enter customers in a datagridview. The `CustomerType` column is a custom control and when the user clicks the button, a search form `Form2` pops up.

The search form is populated with a list of type `CustomerType`. The user can select a record by double-clicking on the row, and this object should be set in the custom control. The `DataGridView` should then display the `Description` property but in the background each cell should hold the value (ie. the `CustomerType` instance).

The relevant code is located in the following classes:

The column class:

```
public class DataGridViewCustomerTypeColumn : DataGridViewColumn
{
    public DataGridViewCustomerTypeColumn()
        : base(new CustomerTypeCell())
    { }

    public override DataGridViewCell CellTemplate
    {
        get { return base.CellTemplate; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null && !value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(CustomerTypeCell)))
            {
                throw new InvalidCastException("Should be CustomerTypeCell.");
            }

            base.CellTemplate = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The cell class:

```
public class CustomerTypeCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{
    public CustomerTypeCell()
        : base()
    { }

    public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex, object initialFormattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
    {
        base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue, dataGridViewCellStyle);

        CustomerTypeSearch ctl = DataGridView.EditingControl as CustomerTypeSearch;

        if (this.Value == null)
            ctl.Value = (CustomerType)this.DefaultNewRowValue;
        else
            ctl.Value = (CustomerType)this.Value;
    }

    public override Type EditType
    {
        get { return typeof(CustomerTypeSearch); }
    }

    public override Type ValueType
    {
        get { return typeof(CustomerType); }
    }

    public override object DefaultNewRowValue
    {
        get { return null; }
    }
}
```

And the custom control:

```
public partial class CustomerTypeSearch : UserControl, IDataGridViewEditingControl
{
    private DataGridView dataGridView;
    private int rowIndex;
    private bool valueChanged = false;
    private CustomerType value;

    public CustomerTypeSearch()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public CustomerType Value
    {
        get { return this.value; }
        set 
        { 
            this.value = value;

            if (value != null)
                textBoxSearch.Text = value.Description;
            else
                textBoxSearch.Clear();
        }
    }

    private void buttonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f = new Form2();

        DialogResult dr = f.ShowDialog(this);

        if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Value = f.SelectedValue;
        }
    }

    #region IDataGridViewEditingControl implementation

    public object EditingControlFormattedValue
    {
        get 
        {
            if (this.value != null)
                return this.value.Description;
            else
                return null;
        }
        set 
        { 
            if (this.value != null)
                this.value.Description = (string)value; 
        }
    }

    public object GetEditingControlFormattedValue(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
    {
        return EditingControlFormattedValue;
    }

    public void ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
    {
        this.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        this.Font = dataGridViewCellStyle.Font;
    }

    public int EditingControlRowIndex
    {
        get { return rowIndex; }
        set { rowIndex = value; }
    }

    public bool EditingControlWantsInputKey(Keys key, bool dataGridViewWantsInputKey)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public void PrepareEditingControlForEdit(bool selectAll)
    {
        //No preparation needs to be done 
    }

    public bool RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public DataGridView EditingControlDataGridView
    {
        get { return dataGridView; }
        set { dataGridView = value; }
    }

    public bool EditingControlValueChanged
    {
        get { return valueChanged; }
        set { valueChanged = value; }
    }

    public Cursor EditingPanelCursor
    {
        get { return base.Cursor; }
    }

    #endregion

    private void CustomerTypeSearch_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        buttonSearch.Left = this.Width - buttonSearch.Width;
        textBoxSearch.Width = buttonSearch.Left;
    }
}
```

However, the `DataGridView` is not displaying the text and it also is not keeping the `CustomerType` value for each cell.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please post the relevant code here.

Comment: Override the `ToString()` method in `CustomerType` class. `DataGirdView` shows only strings by using `ToString()` method.

Comment: I did that and it works. However PatseFormattedValue wants to cast the displayed string in my object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, override `ToString()` method to your `CustomerType` class.

Second, to avoid parsing errors, modify the following method in `CustomerTypeSearch` class :

```
public CustomerType Value
{
    get { return this.value; }
    set
    {
        this.value = value;

        if (value != null)
            textBoxSearch.Text = value.Description;
        else
            textBoxSearch.Clear();

        valueChanged = true;
        if ((EditingControlDataGridView.CurrentCell as CustomerTypeCell) != null)
            (EditingControlDataGridView.CurrentCell as CustomerTypeCell).Value = value;
    }
}
```

Then, add this function to the `CustormerTypeCell` class :

```
protected override bool SetValue(int rowIndex, object value)
{
    if (value != null)
        return base.SetValue(rowIndex, value);
    return false;
}
```

Finally, add this to handle data errors :

```
private void dataGridView_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = false;
}
```

Comment: I just get the message: 'Exception occurred in the DataGridView'. Somehow value is always null.

Comment: I can't reproduce your exception. When is the ParseFormattedValue function called ?

Comment: When focus is leaving the cell (eg. pressing Tab).

Comment: Still doesn't work. However, I noticed that if this line:                                 `this.EditingControlDataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);` is added just below `valueChanged = true;`, it will raise the the `ParseFormattedValue` event.